# Pregunta con respuesta a API de React y C#

Tags: c#, reactjs, api

estoy intentando hacer una petición a una api creada por mi, desde React a una api rest c# básica. Mi problema es que al hacer la petición me devuelve la respuesta 200 pero no me devuelve ningún tipo de objeto.

El código de la api (servidor)

```
// GET: api/Usuario
        public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {
            var usuario = obtenerUsuarios();
            

            return Ok(usuario.ToList());
        }

        private IEnumerable<UsuarioDTO> obtenerUsuarios()
        {
            List<UsuarioDTO> user = new List<UsuarioDTO>
            {
                new UsuarioDTO(){ Id = 1, Nombre= "Pato" },
                new UsuarioDTO(){ Id = 2, Nombre= "Ganso" },
            };
            return user;
        }
```

EL código de react (cliente)

```
const loginApi =({user, pass})=>{
    let myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

    let requestOptions = {
        method: "GET",
        
      };

      return fetch(`${apipath}api/Usuario`, requestOptions).then(
        (response) => {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if (response.status == 200) {
              return resolve(response);
            } else {
              return reject("Error");
            }
          });
        }
      );

};
```

[image: Respuesta]

Como se puede ver en la respuesta me dice que ok, 200. Pero sin embargo no veo ningún objeto q corresponda a mi usuario.

PD: En postman funciona perfectamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas obteniendo el objeto Request, por eso te imprime todo lo que muestra tu imagen, solo agrega .json() o .text()

```
const loginApi =({user, pass})=>{
let myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

let requestOptions = {
    method: "GET",
    
  };

  return fetch(`${apipath}api/Usuario`, requestOptions).then(
    (response) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (response.status == 200) {
          return resolve(response.json());
        } else {
          return reject("Error");
        }
      });
    }
  );
```

};